Jenkins Plugin Upgrade strategy in kubernetes on shared NFS
Trying to upgrade an older Jenkins and Plugins using a plugins.txt file.  Using a custom build base from  jenkins/jenkins:2.462.1-alpine-jdk21 running on Kubernetes.  Set up JENKINS_HOME as /var/jenkins_home as a mounted NFS share.  However, when trying to do a rolling deployment with a new image with updated plugins, the first pod running the old plugins locks file resources on the NFS share files in JENKINS_HOME from removing or upgrading the plugins.
The following error is seen in the logs for each updated plugin:
SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Inspecting plugin /var/jenkins_home/plugins/azure-keyvault.jpi
Also:       Also:   java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/jenkins_home/plugins/azure-keyvault/WEB-INF/lib/.nfs1a11aaa00000000000000123: Resource busy

I deleted the Kubernetes Jenkins deployment and redeployed a single pod, but I want to see if there is a better upgrade strategy for Jenkins and plugins on a shared mount in Kubernetes.
Secondly, in starting up with a single pod, I noticed old plugins in JENKINS_HOME not getting removed as part of the upgrade, or the newer version hasn't been upgraded yet, in the image I have a newer version of javadoc in the image.  See error below.  Should I remove and clean up the plugins/ folder on the JENKINS_HOME mount before the upgrade?
SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Maven Integration plugin v3.23 (maven-plugin)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Maven Integration plugin (maven-plugin 3.23)
 - Update required: Javadoc Plugin (javadoc 1.1) to be updated to 233.vdc1a_ec702cff or higher

